# Access token to encrypt or not

Tags: security, authentication, access-token

We store access token in database, it is a random string, it is stored as it is, without encryption.

Is it must be encrypted? Is there some security risks?

Comment: That depends on the used client platform and what you can do when you own the token. Hence you need a security evaluation of your software to answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the purpose of these tokens.
Access Tokens usually are never stored.
They are not random strings, but rather short-lived objects that are issued based on strict requirements (validation) and signed by HMAC and a secret key.
All these are measures to make them secure.

If they are just random strings, they do not fulfill any of these measures.

Answer (score 1):

You could encrypt the token when it is stored in the database to avoid leaking it when a database breach occurs. But then of course it then comes down to how you've protected/stored the key with which you've encrypted the token.

If you believe you can protect the encryption key better than the database storage/access, e.g. by using an HSM or secure file storage, then it makes sense to encrypt the token with such a key before storing it.